# Is DataSet really slow in comparison with DataReader?

Tags: .net

I'm trying to create a big .Net application that will handle some data from a database (all the possible operations on the database, insertions, views, sorting, row-based computations...).

I'm not an expert in ADO and I would like to make sure my architecture is optimal. So I'm trying to compare DataSet vs DataReader to know when I have use which one.

I created a dummy table in Oracle and I filled with 2 000 000 records. When I check the size of the table using the Query :

```
select * from dba_segments where Owner = 'TESTUSER'
```

I get something like 100 MB for this table.

I read in MSDN that DataSet loads everything about the table while DataReader is a foreward only reading tool which is faster.

I'm trying to tests the limits of each one, so I wrote the following code :

```
SQL = "Select * from HugeTable"
Command = New OracleCommand(SQL, Me.Connection)
TempDataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter(Command)
TempDataAdapter.FillSchema(DataSet, SchemaType.Source, FullTableName)
TempDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet, FullTableName)
```

If my understanding is correct, I'm exepecting the last line to load 100 MB from the database which will require few seconds I guess (the database is in the same computer)
However when I run this code, it's instantaneous (it runs in few hundredth of seconds and I can't understand why it's.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Why downvoting ? What's wrong with the question ?

Comment: Not my downvote, but think about this: What do you think the DataAdapter uses to fill a DataSet?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand your question

Comment: Steve is pointing out the same thing I did - a DataAdaptor uses a Datareader to fill a DataSet. We are confused because you seem to be asking which is "faster" - Reading from a DataReader or using a DataSet created by reading a DataReader. It is the wrong question.

Comment: It seems like you didn't read the question carefully. What I'm trying to figure out is how much DataSet is slower than DataReader. I'm trying to answer questions like : Does loading 1 million rows takes 2 seconds or 2 minutes ? in order to couple this information with the estimated size of each table (according to business logic) and decide which solution to use for each use case...

Comment: The point is that a DataSet is an in memory object where a DataReader (usually) stores all the data resulting from a query. After that the DataReader is discarded and you can use the DataSet and its tables for your display or other tasks (of course if you have enough memory to keep all that data in memory).. DataReader instead is the lowest level object that you can use to retrieve data from the database. The infrastructure of a DataSet (DataTables,DataRows,DataColumns, DataRelations) are there for your benefit but it doesn't make sense to compare these two classes to discover which is faster.

Comment: Understood. I think the comparison between these two classes may make sense in some cases. Example Let's assume a GridView. DataSet is more flexible than DataReader. So sometimes, I would prefer to use DataSet but if the size of data is huge, my application will crash and then I will have to use DataReader. These are the kind of questions I need to answer. And the answer is based on the size of the tables according to business logics but also based on the limites of each one that I'm trying to explore here

Comment: With this volume of data you should really use paging. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what you're doing. You're right - a dataset does load the entire content of the query result into memory, which may be what you want under certain circumstances.

DataReader is a "fire hose" feeding you data as you read from it. Memory efficient but forward-only. (DataSets are populated from Datareaders!)

So I think you should focus more on what you intend to do with the data to decide how you read it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I'm not trying to confirm what Microsoft has stated in its documentation. I'm trying to check the limits of the speed loss in order to switch from one solution to another... To be more specific, some of my tables will contain x rows and other probably 1000 times x. So I would like to know when the speed loss is significant to check whether to choose this solution or the other...

Comment: You need to think about more then just speed - memory consumption is a big deal here too. If you don't need 100MB in memory at one time, don't do it. Particularly in a multi-request environment (like a web server) several of these running at the same time consuming that much memory will not scale.

Comment: Yes exactly Speed - Memory. And again I'm looking for a way to test the limits of each one and NOT a generic answer such us : DataReader is faster, so use DataReader.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty confused at this point. You say you want to "test the limits" but to what end? Don't you ultimately want to make a decision about which to use? You're right - it won't always be one or the other, which is why I suggested considering your goals.

Comment: Here is an example : Let's assume a GridView. DataSet is more flexible than DataReader. So sometimes, I would prefer to use DataSet but if the size of data is huge, my application will crash and then I will have to use DataReader. These are the kind of questions I need to answer. And the answer is based on the size of the tables according to business logics but also based on the limites of each one that I'm trying to explore here.